# How to match whole word in regex using java split

Tags: java, string, collections, split

Am trying to split word based on my requirement. And i want to split based on whole word.

Example like given below,

```
Actual        -       Expecting

10% to 20%    -     10 to 20%
10% and 60%   -     10 and 60%
5 % to 10 %   -     5 to 10% 
25 to 125     -    no need to change
```

My sample String,

```
 String str = "Zimowski, M. F., Muraki, E., Mislevy, R 10% to 25% J., & Btock, R. D. (1996). BILOG-MG: [mMultiple 10% and 25%-group IRT]( analysis and test maintenance for binary items. Chicago, IL: 5% Scientific) Software).[AQ: â€œZimowski,10 % to 25% Muraki, Mislevy, & Bock, 1996â€�is not cited 10 to 25% in text. Please indicate where a citation 10 and 25% should appear or allow us to delete the reference.]";
```

My expected result

```
String result = "Zimowski, M. F., Muraki, E., Mislevy, R 10 to 25% J., & Btock, R. D. (1996). BILOG-MG: [mMultiple 10 and 25%-group IRT]( analysis and test maintenance for binary items. Chicago, IL: 5% Scientific) Software).[AQ: â€œZimowski,10 to 25% Muraki, Mislevy, & Bock, 1996â€�is not cited 10 to 25% in text. Please indicate where a citation 10 and 25% should appear or allow us to delete the reference.]";
```

I try to split the string at occurrences of "and" , "to". But cleary not completed this(based on requirement).

So, please suggest and let me know.

Comment: Please show what to try ;)

Comment: You should look at Pattern class in Java. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thnks, First i need to check my requirement patter is occurred  or not in respective String

Comment: I read your question like 3 times; and I am still not sure what exactly you want to achieve. You have a table where you describe to get rid of the % character - and then you talk about splitting and commas??? Sorry, but provide a **real** [mcve] please. Including the code you already wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`str = str.replaceAll("(\\d\\d?\\d?\\s?)(%)(\\s)(and|to)(\\s\\d\\d?\\d?\\s?)","$1$3$4$5");`

Comment: Hai @Miguel. I need another one help for How to check ([ ]) this pattern occured or not in a string. Sample String is i mentioned above.

Comment: I know some logic but they are all instead of looping. So, know any regex pattern is there.? Please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [java.util.regex.Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class, specially at the method appendReplacement.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SanJose { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "10% to 20% aaa 10% and 60% bbb 5 % to 10 % ddd 25 to 125";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\s*%\\s+(to|and)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().replace("%", ""));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```